# Flutter Application – Empty GridTile and conditions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of some categories and recipes (food recipes app). So, I have two questions:

1. Why I see empty space, when open the Category? I think it gives SizedBox(), but I can't write null at this place, because of crash.
2. Did I make the correct condition for checking a recipe for a category?

---

**Recipes Tab**

```
    class RecipesTab extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _RecipesTabState createState() => _RecipesTabState();
    }
    
    class _RecipesTabState extends State<RecipesTab> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          initialIndex: 1,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text('Книга рецептов'),
              bottom: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                indicatorColor: Color(0xFF0FA3B1),
                labelColor: Color(0xFF0FA3B1),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'Избранное'),
                  Tab(text: 'Категории'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  Favorite(),
                  Categories(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

---

**Categories**

```
class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoriesState createState() => _CategoriesState();
}

class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  Future<List<Category>> _getCategories() async {
    var data = await http.get(
      "https://ibragimov.xyz:7000/categories/?format=json",
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
    );
    var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));

    List<Category> categories = [];

    for (var i in jsonData) {
      Category category = Category(i['id'], i['name']);

      categories.add(category);
    }
    return categories;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getCategories(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int id) {
                return Card(
                  elevation: 0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[id].name),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  Recipes(snapshot.data[id])));
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class Category {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Category(this.id, this.name);
}
```

---

**Recipes**

```
class Recipes extends StatefulWidget {
  final Category category;
  Recipes(this.category);

  @override
  _RecipesState createState() => _RecipesState();
}

class _RecipesState extends State<Recipes> {
  Future<List<Recipe>> _getRecipes() async {
    var data = await http.get("https://ibragimov.xyz:7000/recipes/?format=json",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
    var jsonData = json.decode(utf8.decode(data.bodyBytes));
    List<Recipe> recipes = [];
    for (var i in jsonData) {
      Recipe recipe =
          Recipe(i['id'], i['name'], i['cost'], i["category"], i["photo"]);
      recipes.add(recipe);
    }
    return recipes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.category.name),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getRecipes(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int id) {
                  return snapshot.data[id].category == widget.category.name
                      ? Card(
                          elevation: 0,
                          margin:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                          child: GridTile(
                            child: Image.network(
                              'https://2recepta.com/recept/omlet-s-pomidorami/omlet-s-pomidorami.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                            ),
                            footer: Text(snapshot.data[id].name),
                            header: Text('data'),
                          ),
                        )
                      : SizedBox.shrink();
                },
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                  maxCrossAxisExtent: 250,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Recipe {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final int cost;
  final String category;
  final String photo;

  Recipe(this.id, this.name, this.cost, this.category, this.photo);
}
```

**Screenshots:**

- [Categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8e0M.png)
- [Chinese kitchen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFuPs.png)
- [Russian kitchen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AivC.png)